# Store Bookmarks in a more Ordered/Structured Way?

Tags: eclipse, bookmarks

Is there a eclipse plugin that allows to store bookmarks in a more structured (group them) and ordered (order them the way I want) way?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Eclipse Marketplace, there seem to be a number of Bookmark enhancement options there. Open **Help > Eclipse Marketplace...** menu item, wait for the dialog to load its contents, and then use the search field at the top to search for `bookmark` (without the quotes).